# Получение списка файлов с версия через PS

Tags: powershell

Всем привет! возник вопрос, как лучше получить вывод на экран списка файлов и их версия (например через тройной дефис)
Список версий получаю

```
Get-ChildItem <путь к папке> -Recurse -file | % { $_.FullName } | foreach-object { "{0}`t{1}" -f $_.Name, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_).FileVersion }
```

Список файлов

```
Get-ChildItem <путь к папке> -Recurse -file | % { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Вложенный цикл foreach-object не нужен. `Get-ChildItem <путь> -Recurse -file | % { "{0} --- {1}" -f $_.Name, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls "C:\tmp" | select name, @{n = 'version'; e = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}} | ft
```